# How to remove padding in the case with iPhone X and newer models?

Tags: css, iphone, padding

Is there anybody who knows: How to remove the padding from the left and right of the display in the case of iPhone X and other iPhone models?

[image]

```css
  body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }
    *{ margin : 0; padding : 0;box-sizing: border-box; }
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right)       env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
   <body style="background-color: black">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust for all four `padding` parameters using the appropriate `env(safe-area-inset-*)` value:

```css
    body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }
    *{ margin : 0; padding : 0;box-sizing: border-box; }
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
   <body style="background-color: black">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I used your code, but the fields didn't disappear.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe on my physical iPhone X device with [this Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/ThornyHarmlessCarriers#index.html). I would encourage you to test this with an actual device rather than a simulator/emulator, which may not properly render edge cases like this one.

Comment: Yes, I used two simulators: one in Chrome browser and one public such as BrowserStack Live, but they return different results, and there is no iPhone at hand to check.

Comment: I would be very wary of the results from a simulator in this instance - as I said, this is probably an edge case that doesn't get properly rendered in simulators like this. Use a service like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/real-device-cloud) to get a more accurate idea of what it will look like on an actual device (they offer a significant amount of testing time free up-front).